# Lifting of a etale cover over a normal crossing divisor.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, covering-spaces

I ran into the following statement in a talk. Assume we are in characteristic zero. Let $X$ be an smooth affine variety, let $X\to Z$ be an open immersion with dense image, such that $Z$ is smooth and proper, and $Z-X$ is a normal crossings divisor. Then if we have an etale map $Y\to X$, there is an extension $Y'\to Z$.

I can't find a proof of this fact. When I asked the speaker, he said that it is in SGA, but that doesn't really narrow down the search.

Comment: What do you know about $Y'$?

Comment: @Hoot All I know is that $Y'$ is meant to be an etale map over $Z$

Comment: For a start take $X = Y = A^1 \setminus 0$, $Z = P^1$, and try to extend the map $Y \to X$, $z \mapsto z^2$.

Comment: @PaxKivimae Is it possible you could uncheck my answer? My second answer is totally wrong (I, like any reasonable human being, confess to not having gone through Gabber-Ramero thoroughly...) due to not understanding at all what logarithmic étale cohomology is, and I would like to delete my answer.

Comment: @SimoneWeil This is why this site is great: you admitted your mistake on the internet. I have unchecked your answer.

Comment: @Pax Kivimae Do you not think people on the internet admit their mistakes?

Comment: @SimoneWeil I could probably have phrased that better, it sounds a bit weird. But yes, on r/math, it is a very different story.